# MFC Application Deployment with VS2010

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I've created two MFC applications which compile and run ok from the IDE. However let's say that the second application wasn't created using App wizard, instead I copied the first application folder and then started to rename source files and relevant information such as string table, version etc. so that the second application was different and unique respect to application #1. Both applications are SDI type and the issue that I'm having is that when I run the setup to install the second application the install aborts because it detects the first one already installed (I guess it is a windows registry key).

I went to app.h, app.cpp, appdoc.h, appdoc.cpp, files and checked lines of code like:

SetAppID(_T("SVGovCfg.AppID.NoVersion")); to make sure that there was no duplication between both apps, However it looks like still something is missing.

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application calls SetRegistryKey() in OnInitInstance(). That key needs to be different between applications. Maybe it's not called in your app and some default value is derived from something - have a look at the MFC source code to see how that's handled.

Answer (score 0):

Search your files for a duplicate UUID with the following regular expression:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]^8-[0-9a-fA-F]^4-[0-9a-fA-F]^4-[0-9a-fA-F]^4-[0-9a-fA-F]^12
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have nothing to do with the applications themselves. When you **install** the application, it's the **setup** program that detects the setup ID. You need to modify the Setup program to differentiate the two.